# Concept of reinterpret cast and static cast ?

Tags: c++, oop, static, reinterpret-cast

I can't understand the concept of reinterpret_cast and static_ cast. Can anyone please explain in easy method using ASCII Art or something like that..

Comment: What have you read about them so far?

Answer (score 1):

IDK about art; but `reinterpret_cast` can only be used with a pointer or reference. It means that you intend to treat the memory pointed to by a pointer to `T` as containing an object of type `U`. If it does not contain such an object (as defined by the strict-aliasing rules in the C++ standard) then it is undefined behaviour.

`static_cast` performs a conversion. With a pointer or a reference, it is similar to `reinterpret_cast`, but it enforces that `T` and `U` must be compatible types. With an object type, it looks for a defined conversion between those two object types.

Comment: I saw somewhere it was used in reading/writing binary files what is its purpose there ? Kindly explain with easy examples